# Liferay: Page Name vs Title and Uniqueness

Tags: layout, liferay, portlet

What's the difference between Page Name and Page Title?

What is the point/use for each one?

In LayoutImpl, they work exactly the same, as two arbitrary text fields, so I guess the difference is in application logic or purpose for them.

I read page name is not unique, is Title unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not one and the same[image]

In the above picture you can give a different title to that of a page name. And the same thing is displayed in the head part of the HTML in portal_normal.vm

`<title>$the_title - $company_name</title>`

Title is not unique.

Comment: Thanks! But why needing both from usage point of view? What is the most appropiated for a navigator?

Comment: Page name is displayed in the navigation, Title is being displayed in the <title> tag of the page. From the user point of view, to navigate within the portal, Page name is appropriate. Title is read only and nice to have.